# JQuery UI dialog - changing title color only partially works

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm using JQuery UI's dialog module, got it all working, and am mostly able to style it ok, but there are one or two oddities that I can't figure out:

1) I am trying to change the color of the title bar from default to purple. Here is my CSS:

```
.ui-dialog-title {
font-family: 'Andika', sans-serif;
color: #FFFFCC;  
background-color:#330033;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar {
   background-color:#330033;
}
```

It half-works: the font changes, and I get a purple rectangle behind the words, but the rest of the bar stays the default color. Changing .widget-header doesn't help.

2) I am trying to change the container border color. Here is my CSS:

```
.ui-dialog {
background-color:#330033;
}
```

Again it half-works - most of the border goes purple, but there are two little white lines left. I've tried making sure I also change the resize-handles, which made the lines thinner but didn't get rid of them completely.

Here's a screenshot to show what I'm currently getting:
[image: Dialog Box Problems]

And here's the code where I create the dialog box, just in case I'm messing something up at this point (though can't see what):

```
//called by 'Demos' button onclick
function demos() {
var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog">Coming Soon</div>');
var $title = "Demos";
dialog($dialog, $title);

....    

function dialog(dialog, title) {
$title = title;
$dialog = dialog;
$dialog.dialog({show: {effect: "blind", duration: 500}}, {title:$title}, {width:700},     
{height:400}, {modal: true});
$dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Edit to add: here is the HTML with the buttons that call the dialog:

```
<div id="portfolio" class ="grey">
        <b>PORTFOLIO</b>
        <br />
        <div id="buttonHolder">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Websites" onclick="websites()">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Apps" onclick="apps()">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Demos" onclick="demos()">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Games" onclick="games()">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Resources" onclick="resources()">
        </div>            
    </div>
```

Edit to add again: this is what I have if I remove the styling on the #dialog div:
[image: More dialog problems]
???

Comment: It looks like you're targeting the wrong element for the title bar. It's hard to tell though without your HTML markup. Try targeting the parent of `.ui-dialog-titlebar`

Comment: That's not how mine looks -> http://jsfiddle.net/fngXH/

Comment: adeneo2, I style #dialog to have a grey background, hence the grey on mine . . . I'm curious about the white middle though, I'd have assumed without the the #dialog styling you'd end up with all purple . . . hmm interesting . . .

Comment: yeah if I remove the #dialog styling I get that white stripe . . . guess that explains the thin white lines at the edges, but I've no clue why the white stripe is there in the first place . . .

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change this:

```
.ui-dialog { background-color:#330033; }
```

to:

```
.ui-dialog { background:#330033; }
```

Comment: I can't vote you up because I don't have enough rep, but thank you :D